# Pause an external SVG animation

Tags: html, svg

You can pause an SVG using `document.getElementById("mysvg").`[`pauseAnimations()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SVGSVGElement). However that only seems to work for inline SVGs.

Is there any way to pause an SVG animation that is included using `<img src="my.svg"/>`?

Comment: No. There isn't.

Comment: when SVG is used in an image context you can't interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

So as Paul LeBeau said you can't do it with an image. You *can* do it - apparently - using `<object>`, something like this:

```
<object id="mysvg" type="image/svg+xml" data="myfile.svg"/>
```

And then access it through:

```
mysvg.contentDocument
```

That is restricted by the CORS policy which unfortunately means it doesn't work when accessing files via the `file://` protocol. In my case (Doxygen) I needed that so I just gave up an included the SVG inline using Doxygen itself like this:

```
\htmlinclude "myfile.svg"
```

Comment: could you please help me out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64982804/pause-resume-svg-animation-on-android-webview